# Implementing Universal Search in a Django Application

Tags: python, django, search, inheritance, django-forms

We have a large Django application made up of a large number of different views (some of which  contain forms). As with most large applications, we use a base layout template that contains the common layout elements across the applications (mainly a header and a footer), which the templates for all of our views extend.

What we are looking to do is create a universal search box in our application, accessible on every page, which allows users to perform searches across the entire application, and want to place the search box inside the header, which involves placing a `form` inside our base layout template. This means that every view in our application will need to be able to handle the submission of this search form. Once this search form is submitted, we will need to redirect the user to another view containing the search results.

However, we are struggling to come up with a pattern to handle this. Does anyone know of functionality built into Django that will help us to build this? Failing that, can anyone suggest a good strategy for modifying our application so that we can handle  this use-case without having to modify a large number of existing views (which we don't have the resources to do at the moment)?

Please note that the focus of this question is intended to be the best way to handle the submission of a form which appears in every view, and not strategies for implementing a universal search algorithm (which we have already figured out).

**Ideas Explored So Far**

- Our first idea was to create a base `View` class that implements handling the universal search form submission, and have each of our views extend this. However, this is not possible because we already have views that inherit from a number of different Django view classes (`TemplateView`, `ListView`, `FormView` and `DeleteView` being some examples), and to be able to build our own common view class would mean either writing our own version of these Django view classes to inherit from our own view base class, or re-writing a large number of our views so they don't use the Django view classes.
- Our next idea was to implement a mixin that would handle the universal search form submission, in an attempt to add this functionality to all our views in a way that allows us to continue using the different Django view classes. However, this brought to light two new problems: (a) how could we do this without modifying each of our views to become a form view, and (b) how can we do this in a way that allows the form handling logic to play nicely when mixed in to existing `FormView`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like such an obvious question that maybe I'm overlooking something. But as others have said your universal search form should not make a POST request to the view that rendered the current page.

Each html form has an `action` attribute. The attribute of your search form should point towards an URL. Probably something like `/search`. That url would have a view behind it that handled the POST request from the form and returned the search results. Django has URL template tags to make this easy. `{% url 'myapp.views.search' %}` will give you the correct url for the `search` view function if it lived inside the `views` module in `myapp`. So the relevant bit of html in your base template would be something like:

```
<form action="{% url 'myapp.views.search' %}">
    <input type="text" name="qs" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

If you are planning on displaying the search results on a new page there is absolutely no need to return JSON or anything like that. Just have a search view that looks like this

```
def search(request):
    query = request.POST.get('qs', '')
    results = SomeModel.objects.filter(name=query) # Your search algo goes here
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', dict(results=results))
```

Comment: Oh dear - quite ashamed I didn't see that, of course thats the correct way to do it. I think I over-complicated the problem in my head :) BTW I'm assuming that the url should be surrounded by `{% ... %}`?

Comment: Ha! :) I wondered if it was something like that. Yes of course you are right. I'll edit the answer. And I usually use named urls. Which I think look a bit nicer. So `{% url search %}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling the form submission on every view of the application, you can implement a separate `view` (endpoint), which handles all the `search queries`. (an endpoint which returns JSON result) since you dont want to add overhead of rendering the whole page with that view. So the search query (which client side AJAX performs to the webserver) will return `JSON` response, and the Javascript can render that response. This way you can keep the `search` view isolated from the rest of the views. ([Django REST](http://django-rest-framework.org/) will be helpful in this case)

And this `search` form will be included in your `base` template, so your search box is accessible from the entire application, and it submits to the same view. And the AJAX function will handle the server response for rendering it.

Comment: This sounds along the right lines - one thing I forgot to mention in the question (now updated) is that on submission of the search form we need to then redirect to a view containing the search results. Do you know of an example which shows how to implement a separate endpoint in this way?

Comment: Here is a quickstart guide on implementing it http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization.html

Comment: This looks very promising - looks like we could hook the rest call into the search form using some custom javascript, and that this framework can handle redirecting the user to another view as it's response. Many thanks for your input, will have a play with this now :)

Comment: @aychedee came up with a simpler solution which suits our needs, but still +1 for a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to create another SearchView which takes the query and displays the results.  I am not sure if the results have to be displayed differently depending on which page the search has been performed from but it does not seem like.

The form would not have anything to do with the other views.  You could just hard code it in the base template.

Comment: Thanks for your input - though I don't think this quite solves our problem. Implementing a separate view to display results is not a problem - we are more trying to work out how we can write logic that can respond to search form submissions, but is independent of the view that is currently being displayed.